# Finding EC2 status using EC2 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

Is there any way to find out status of AWS EC2 instances, which are running on various different regions, from one EC2 instance which is present in any one of region by using EC2 API tool ?

How this is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer :-

`ec2-describe-instances instance-ID  --region region`

Example :-

`ec2-describe-instances i-f82d5ca0 --region eu-west-1`

Where instance ID is EC2 instance ID which is located in region `eu-west-1`

Thats all .

Answer (score 0):

Or in the new unified AWS CLI, this is slightly different:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-f82d5ca0
```

You can also change the `--output` into `json`, `text`, or a `table`